# To compute a value for overall dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I was trying to work on a requirement where I had to compute the value for an entire column based on a formula, here is my below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s={'Fruits':['Apple','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'],
   'month':['201401','201502','201603','201604'],'weight':[2,4,1,6],
   'Quant':[132,178,298,300]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
n=len(p)
std_dev=((1)/(n-1))*(sum([(p['Quant'] - p['weight']) ** 2 for _ in range(n)]))
alpha=2
std_devf= p['Quant'] + alpha*(std_dev)
```

The expected value for std_devf should be a single value. (Eg 100 or 200)

But the O/P I'm getting is this, which is based on every Fruits-

```
0     45198.666667
1     80914.000000
2    235522.000000
3    230796.000000
```

How would I be able to just get a single value, based on the formula? Is it due to my formula that I'm getting values in this manner?

Comment: can you provide the formula the way you read/got it?

Comment: @mozway here is the link to the documentation I was reading- https://help.sap.com/viewer/c95f1f0dcd9549628efa8d7d653da63e/7.0.4/en-US/c12bc95360267614e10000000a174cb4.html

Comment: Also I have updated my code, had to add few steps in the code.

Comment: According to your list in the `std_dev`,  you are trying to sum the same dataframe by four times? You know you are actually getting a list of four same dataframes with what you have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `std_dev` formula needs to be fixed. You are creating a list of 4 dataframes and summing them up. However, the link you have provided did not mention that way. According to the link, it should be like this:

```
n = len(p)
std_dev = (1/(n-1)*(sum([(p['Quant'][i] - p['weight'][i]) ** 2 for i in range(n)]))) ** 0.5
alpha = 2
std_devf= p['Quant'] + alpha*(std_dev)
```

On the other hand, you are looking for the expected value of the `std_devf` or the bound limit? If that's the case, the result will have decimals as in the link, but you can always round it up to two decimals.

```
round(std_devf,2)
Out[33]: 
0    675.84
1    721.84
2    841.84
3    843.84
Name: Quant, dtype: float64
```

### Edit

If you want to find the expected value of `std_devf` by summing the product of `weight` and `std_devf`, you can make a new column for `std_devf` and do the normal operation.

```
p["std_devf"]= p['Quant'] + alpha*(std_dev)
expected_value = sum(p['weight']*p['std_devf'])

round(expected_value,2)
Out[5]: 10143.91
```

Comment: Let me know if I need to correct anything

Comment: Thanks for the response. What about having std_devf, I don't want it to have a series based values, like above output you have mentioned, I just need a single value to be computed. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Just to confirm, your expected value is the sum of weight multiply with std_devf?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I have added the edit, is this your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

for calculating your standard deviation you can follow my method
import math
s=0
for i in range(n):
s=s+sum([(p['Quant'][i] - p['weight'][i])])*(sum([(p['Quant'][i] -p['weight'[i])]))

std_dev=s/(n-1)
std_dev=math.sqrt(std_dev)
alpha=2
std_devf= p['Quant'] + alpha*(std_dev)

Hope it solves your  query, you can find the image of my solution on below link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HH5b.png